# Как грамотно организовать подгрузку только необходимого css?

Tags: php, css

**Делаю мультилендинг с помощью php.**

"Если utm метка такая, то переменные заголовков равны вот этому. Если utm другая, то переменные заголовков равны тому-то". Выкатываю значения переменных в разметку через <?php echo

Слышал про какие-то практики подгрузки только тех свойств css, которые в данный момент необходимы. Проще говоря, зачем мне подгружать всю таблицу стилей, когда можно разбить её на более мелкие и так же через echo по utm подгружать. Сказано-сделано, костыль закодирован, но остаётся острое ощущение того, что:

1. так уже никто не делает
2. наверняка есть какое-то готовое решение

хотя  с другой стороны, работает же, да и фиг с ним, не такой уж и большой сайт, чтобы трубка лида каскадной таблицей подавилась

Comment: что-то я не вижу смысла в этом действе, при условии что ваш css будет закэширован браузером.

Comment: просто по utm у меня подгружаются целые блоки, и не хотелось бы, чтобы браузер пользователя съедал тот css, который ему не нужен. Скорость загрузки там, и вот это вот всё

Comment: @YuryFrolov сейчас бы CSS код сильно влиял на скорость загрузки, когда он весит ничтожно мало....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вот решение:

```js
<?php
  if (utm == 1) {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" encoding="utf-8">
      var css_link = document.createElement('link');
      css_link.rel  = 'stylesheet';
      css_link.type = 'text/css';
      css_link.href = "путь_до_файла";
      document.head.appendChild(css_link);
    </script>';
  }
?>
```